# Editing a csv file with python

Tags: python, excel, csv

Ok so I'm looking to create a program that will interact with an excel spreadsheet. The idea that seemed to work the most is converting it to a csv file. I've managed to make a program that prints the data but I want it to edit it and thus change the results in the csv file itself.

Sorry if it's a bit confusing as my programming skills aren't great.

Heres the code:

```
import csv
with open('wert.csv') as csvfile:
  freq=csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
  for row in freq:
    print(row[0],row[1],row[2])
```

If anyone has a better idea on how to make this program work then it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the pandas package, a widely used data analysis/manipulation library.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('foo.csv')
#change data here, see pandas documentation
data.to_csv('bar.csv')
```

You can find the docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/)

Answer (score 0):

If you csv file is composed of just numbers (floats) or numbers and a header, you can try reading it with:

```
import numpy as np
data=np.genfromtxt('name.csv',delimiter=',',skip_header=1)
```

Then modify your data in python, and save it with:

```
data_modified=data**2 #for example    

np.savetxt('name_modified.csv',data_modified,delimiter=',',header='whaterverheader,you,want')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the excel file directly using pandas and do the processing directly

```
import pandas
measured_data = pandas.read_excel(filename)
```